# javascript: How to get highest layer of json object as array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

With an array of objects in a form like this:

```
[
    { 
        1429={
            {
                8766={...},
                8483={...},
                7345={...}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        9041={...}
    }
]
```

how could i get back an array like this?:
[1429, 9041]

If the array of objects would be in another structure this code would work:

```
var obj = {
    "5": "some",
    "8": "thing"
};
var keys = $.map(obj, function (value, key) {
    return key;
});

console.log(keys);
```

That would return [5, 8]. But in my example it just would return the indexes [0,1]

Even if I wouldn't know the depth of the object - is it possible to get the values on that level? I dont need the indexes, I need those values. I couldn't find anything about it so far. Any tips for me maybe?

P.S.: I know that i could work out something with these keys and a loop, but I'm just asking for a simplier way to do it.

Regards

Comment: while json decode give second param as true in php

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the wrong terminology - I edited it already :)

Comment: [`[].concat.apply([], input.map(Object.keys))`](http://jsbin.com/eyILidU/1/)

Comment: `$.map(obj, Object.keys)`?

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Already solved it thanks to Mohamed Ali Jamaoui. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for the keys in a json object, you can get them this way:

```
Object.keys(obj);
```

for the object example:

```
var obj = {
"5": "some",
"8": "thing"
};
```

you will get:

```
["5","8"]
```

for an array of object of this type:

```
var arrayObject = [{},{},{}];
```

you can use a map and get the keys:

```
var keys = arrayObject.map(function(k){
   return Object.keys(k);
});
```

keys is an array of arrays of keys. Example, for the following object (similar to your data structure):

```
var l= [
{ 
    1429:{

            8766: "test",
            8483:"test",
            7345: "test"

    }
},
{
    9041: "test"
}
];
```

you will get:

```
[["1429"],["9041"]]
```

apply concat and you will get what you are looking for. Here how to apply concat in the case of multiple arrays.

```
var arrayOfKeys = [].concat.apply([], keys);
```

now you will get:

```
["1429","9041"];
```

Comment: Thanks! But that didn't work. It would work in this example: // array like object with random key ordering
var an_obj = { 100: "a", 2: "b", 7: "c"};
alert(Object.keys(an_obj)); // will alert "2, 7, 100"

Comment: have you tried the updated answer which loops over the object

Comment: Thank you Mörre but that doesnt seem to work in the structure it currently is. It just returns 0 but not the value :(

Comment: what is the difference between your data structure and the data structure l in the above example

Comment: Alright! Thank you sooo much! That was exactly what I was looking for!!! I didn't know about the map function, but i do know now :)

Comment: No, sorry. Did you edit your post meanwhile? Because I didn't read the solution at first ;) But now it work's all perfectly well!

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case you could use

```
var keys = [];
root.forEach(function(v) { keys = keys.concat(Object.keys(v)); });
```

If instead you have a tree of arrays and you want the keys of all other objects instead (but not recursing into objects) then a simple recursive function would do it:

```
function topKeys(x) {
   if (x && x.constructor === Array) {
       var result = [];
       x.forEach(function(item) {
           result = result.concat(topKeys(item));
       });
       return result;
   } else if (typeof x === "object") {
       return Object.keys(x);
   } else {
       return [];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But to be honest I didnt even try it because Mohamed Ali Jamaoui already created a short practical function. But I appreciate your help! :)